# Why is this not correct way of calculating real value ( stupid question)?

Tags: finance

- inflation $= 3\%$ per year,
- amount of time $= 5$ years,
- nominal value = $\$5070.6$,
- real value  = ?
- real value* $1.03^5 = \$5070.6 $,
  real value = 4373.94, this is correct answer
- why not : $5070.6\times(1-0.3)^5 =$ real value, which gives answer $\$4354.3$ for real value

Comment: If $\$5070.6$ is the value at $t=0$, then at $t=5$ the real value is   $\$5070.6\cdot (1-0.03)^5=\$ 4345.3$. So you're right.

Comment: @callculus42 - No, they are not. The inflation rate is the percentage increase of prices this year over prices last year, not the percentage decrease of prices last year over prices this year, which is what the $(1-0.03)^5$ is treating it as. $\frac 1{1+x}\ne (1-x)$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, I agree. Thanks for the correction.